# issue using deepcopy function for cython classes

Tags: cython, pickle, deep-copy

I've been playing with Cython recently for the speed ups, but when I was trying to use `copy.deepcopy()` some error occurred.Here is the code:

```
from copy import deepcopy

cdef class cy_child:
    cdef public:
        int move[2]
        int Q
        int N
    def __init__(self, move):
        self.move = move
        self.Q = 0
        self.N = 0      

a = cy_child((1,2))

b = deepcopy(a)
```

This is the error:
`can't pickle _cython_magic_001970156a2636e3189b2b84ebe80443.cy_child objects`

How can I solve the problem for this code?

Comment: I've only looked at `deepcopy` in relation to be `numpy` arrays (questions about the `memo` parameter).  But for custom classes you have to define a `__deepcopy__` method.  Otherwise it uses some generic process inherited from base class (`object`).  `cython's` base might not implement it.  Why do you want `deepcopy`?

Comment: Actually the code that I have used here is just a basic example of main code. In the main code I have many variables including `memoryviews`, `numpy` arrays, and also other objects which have plenty of parameters. So I thought `deepcopy` is much more sensible to use.

Comment: The class cy_child has plenty of functions in it, so I want to use `deepcopy` to be able to use the functions for it.

Comment: `deepcopy` has to know how to copy all of the attributes of your instance.  The error message suggests that the default `deepcopy` makes use of `pickle`, possibly creating the copy by pickling, and then unpickling.  That sounds inefficient, but it may be the most general way of recursing down all the layers of the class.

Comment: The most recent version of Cython apparently has pickle support, so it's possible that if you upgrade Cython it'll work

Comment: No I updated cython, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `hpaulj` says in the comments, `deepcopy` looks to use `pickle` by default to do its work. Cython `cdef class`es didn't used to be pickleable. [In recent versions of Cython they are where possible](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#026-2017-07-19) (see also http://blog.behnel.de/posts/whats-new-in-cython-026.html) but pickling the array looks to be a problem (and even without the array I didn't get it to work).

The solution is to implement the relevant functions yourself. I've done [`__deepcopy__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) since it's simple but alternatively you could implement the [pickle protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances)

```
def __deepcopy__(self,memo_dictionary):
    res = cy_child(self.move)
    res.Q = self.Q
    res.N = self.N
    return res
```

I suspect that you won't need to do that in the future as Cython improves their pickle implementation.

---

A note on `memo_dictionary`: Suppose you have

```
a=[None]
b=[A]
a[0]=B
# i.e. A contains a link to B and B contains a link to A
c = deepcopy(a)
```

`memo_dictionary` is used by `deepcopy` to keep a note of what it's already copied so that it doesn't loop forever. You don't need to do much with it yourself. However, if your `cdef` class contains a Python object (including another cdef class) you should copy it like this:

```
cdef class C:
    cdef object o
    def __deepcopy__(self,memo_dictionary):
        # ...
        res.o = deepcopy(self.o,memo_dictionary)
        # ...
```

(i.e. make sure it gets passed on to further calls of `deepcopy`)

Comment: Thank you `DavidW`. I suspect if `DavidW` stands for David Wonderful!

Comment: Could you explain what does `memo_dictionary` do and also give me the other reference links which made you come up with this solution if possible?

Comment: I've added an explanation of `memo_dictionary`. I honestly didn't use too many references that I didn't link, but I've added a couple of links about the addition of pickle support.

Comment: Thank you. You are so helpful. I admire your passion to help.