# Using manual deepcopy on cython classes causes memory overflow.Why?

Tags: python-3.x, cython, pickle, deep-copy

I am developing an Intelligent agent for board games using *MCTS algorithm*.
**Monte carlo tree search (MCTS)** is a popular method in AI which is mostly used for games (like GO, Chess, ...). In this method, An agent builds a tree based on states which would be a result of choosing moves allowed in current state. Agent is allowed to search through the tree for limited time. in this period, Agent expands the tree to the nodes which are most promising (for winning a game). 
The picture below shows the process:

[image: MCTS steps in a single iteration (figure from chaslot 2006)]

For more information you can check this link:

1 - http://www.cameronius.com/research/mcts/about/index.html

In root node of the tree, there would be a variable `rootstate` which shows the *current state* of game. A deepcopy of `rootstate` is used to simulate the tree states (future states) as we go deep in the tree.

I used this code for `deepcopy` of `gamestate` class because `deepcopy` doesn't work fine with cython objects due to their problem with pickle protocol:

cdef class gamestate:

```
# ... other functions

def __deepcopy__(self,memo_dictionary):
    res = gamestate(self.size)
    res.PLAYERS = self.PLAYERS
    res.size = int(self.size)
    res.board = np.array(self.board, dtype=np.int32)
    res.white_groups = deepcopy(self.white_groups) # a module which checks if white player has won the game
    res.black_groups = deepcopy(self.black_groups) # a module which checks if black player has won the game
    # the black_groups and white_groups are also cython objects which the same deepcopy function is implemented for them
    # .... etc
    return res
```

Whenever an MCTS iteration starts, a deepcopy of the state is stored in memory. 
The *problem* which occurs is that in the **begining of the game**, 
the iterations per 1 second is between 2000 and 3000 which is expected, but **as the game tree expands**,the iterations per 1 second **decreases** to 1. It get even worse when each iteration takes more time to 
be completed. 
When I checked the **memory usage**, I noticed that it **increases from 0.6 percent to 90 percent** for each time I call the agent to search. 
I had implemented the same algorithm in *pure python* and it has no issues of this type. So I guess the **__deepcopy__ function** causes the problem. I was once suggested to make my own `pickle` protocol for cython objects in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738319/issue-using-deepcopy-function-for-cython-classes/45761602?noredirect=1#comment78496201_45761602), but I am not very much familiar with `pickle` module. 
Can anyone suggest me some protocol to use for my cython objects to get rid of this obstacle.

**Edit 2:**

I add some parts of the code which might help more.
The code below belongs to **deepcopy** of class `unionfind` which is used for `white_groups` and `black_groups` in `gamestate`:

```
cdef class unionfind:
    cdef public:
        dict parent
        dict rank
        dict groups
        list ignored
    cdef __init__(self):
    # initialize variables ...

   def __deepcopy__(self, memo_dictionary):
       res = unionfind()
       res.parent = self.parent
       res.rank = self.rank
       res.groups = self.groups
       res.ignored = self.ignored
       return res
```

this one is the search function which is run during allowed time:

```
cdef class mctsagent:
    def search(time_budget):
        cdef int num_rollouts = 0
        while (num_rollouts < time_budget):
          state_copy = deepcopy(self.rootstate)
          node, state = self.select_node(state_copy) # expansion runs inside the select_node function
          turn = state.turn()
          outcome = self.roll_out(state)
          self.backup(node, turn, outcome)
          num_rollouts += 1
```

Comment: Do the `white_groups` or `black_groups` contain a reference back to the `gamestate` object? It seems like you might have a circular reference and aren't passing the memo_dict into the deepcopy calls you use inside.

Comment: No they have their own variables. It is a simple `unionfind` data structure which has three dictionaries and a list. game state moves are passed to `white_groups` and `black_groups`. the only thing which is returned back to gamestate is boolean which says whether the game is ended by black/white player or not.

Comment: Does this memory explosion happen when you try to deepcopy one of the `white_groups` or `black_groups`? It may not be possible to diagnose the problem without seeing the rest of the `__deepcopy__` code.

Comment: Can the same object occur at multiple places in `white_groups` or `black_groups`? If so, you probably need to be passing along the `memo` dict in your calls to `deepcopy`. Actually, you should probably be doing that regardless of the nesting of your code, just in case your `gamestate` object is caught up in a larger nested structure.

Comment: In each iteration a copy of `rootstate` is passed to the select_node. then the functions keep working on the copy until state of game reaches to a terminal node. then the result back-propagates to root node. but the result thing has nothing to do with state. because in the next iteration, another copy is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is probably the lines

```
res.white_groups = deepcopy(self.white_groups) # a module which checks if white player has won the game
res.black_groups = deepcopy(self.black_groups) # a module which checks if black player has won the game
```

What you should be doing is calling `deepcopy` with the second argument `memo_dictionary`. This is `deepcopy`s record of if it's already copied an object. Without it `deepcopy` ends up copying the same object multiple times (hence the huge memory use)

```
res.white_groups = deepcopy(self.white_groups, memo_dictionary) # a module which checks if white player has won the game
res.black_groups = deepcopy(self.black_groups, memo_dictionary) # a module which checks if black player has won the game
```

> [If the `__deepcopy__()` implementation needs to make a deep copy of a component, it should call the `deepcopy()` function with the component as first argument and the memo dictionary as second argument.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

(edit: just seen that @Blckknght already pointed this out in the comments)

(edit2: `unionfind` looks to mainly contain Python objects. There probably isn't a huge value in it being a `cdef class` and not just a normal class. Also, your current `__deepcopy__` for it doesn't actually make a copy of those dictionaries - you should be doing `res.parent = deepcopy(self.parent, memo_dictionary)` etc.. If you just made it a normal class this would be implemented automatatically)

Comment: Your suggestion about using `memo_dictionary` for `self.parent` was really useful. Now it works just fine. Thank you again @DavidW

Comment: I thought if I make the `unionfind` object a normal python class, then  `gamestate` couldn't inherit `unionfind` because it's a python class. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MasoudMasoumiMoghadam You're right - I hadn't realised you needed to inherit from `unionfind`.

Comment: There is one thing that was not discussed yet. Could `pickle` or `cpickle` module come in handy with the code? How can I make the current code run faster by using these modules? What do you suggest @DavidW?

Comment: `pickle`/`cpickle` solve a more complicated problem than `deepcopy` (loading/saving reliably on different computers with different versions of Python). Therefore my guess is that they're likely to be (slightly) slower. If you need `pickle` anyway it's nice that the code you write gives you `deepcopy` for free but I doubt if using `pickle` will help with speed. This is a guess though - I haven't measured it.

Comment: Thank you anyway. Good luck